# Continuously fade in and out

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I have this JavaScript to make the div flash every two seconds. I was wondering if I could add anything into this current function so that the div fades in and out instead of appearing and disappearing with no transition.

JavaScript

```
  <script language = "javascript">
        function flash()
        {
            var blinker = 2000
            var timeIn = setInterval(function() {
                var element = document.getElementById('sign');
                element.style.visibility = (element.style.visibility == 'hidden' ? '' : 'hidden');
            }, blinker);        
        }
    </script>
```

HTML div

```
 <div class = "sign" id = "sign">

    <p> hello </p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it to **continue** fading in and out.. you could try something like this:

```
function keepFading($obj) {
    $obj.fadeToggle(2000, function () {
        keepFading($obj)
    });
}
keepFading($("#sign"));
```

[See working example in Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FxPDj/2/)

This function would then work on any jquery object you pass it. So if you have something else you want to do the same thing you can just call it like `keepFading($("#someOtherEle"));`

For this to work, you'll need to make sure that jquery is included. You can then put the above code at the bottom of your html... or in your head if you wrap in a `$(document).ready( ... )`

Comment: where and how do I use the "$(document).ready( ... )"? I have never used JQuery before

Comment: @user3087015, use it within the `<head>`, after including jquery. If you put it in your `<head>` it will look something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/FxPDj/3/

Answer (score 2):

Since you've tagged jQuery, you can simplify it to:

```
$('#sign').fadeIn(2000); // fade-in in 2 seconds
```

and

```
$('#sign').fadeOut(2000); // fade-out in 2 seconds
```

or as pointed out by user: Bondye

```
function flash() {
    $('#sign').fadeToggle(2000);
}
```

Comment: If you don't want to check if it is hidden or visible, you could use `fadeToggle()` : http://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/

Comment: @Bondye - Yes. Can simplify it even further by using fadeToggle().

Comment: Does this mean I have to change the JavaScript tag for the JQuery to work?

Comment: @user3087015 - Change your `flash()` function as updated in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` on pure javascript:

```
 function fadeOut(id,val){ 
     if(isNaN(val)){ 
         val = 9;
     }
     document.getElementById(id).style.opacity='0.'+val;

     //For IE
     document.getElementById(id).style.filter='alpha(opacity='+val+'0)';
     if(val>0){
         val–;
         setTimeout('fadeOut("'+id+'",'+val+')',90);
     }else{
         return;
     }
 }

 function fadeIn(id,val){
     // ID of the element to fade, Fade value[min value is 0]
     if(isNaN(val)){ 
         val = 0;
     }

     document.getElementById(id).style.opacity='0.'+val;
     //For IE
     document.getElementById(id).style.filter='alpha(opacity='+val+'0)';

     if(val<9){
         val++;
         setTimeout('fadeIn("'+id+'",'+val+')',90);
     }else{
         return;
     }
 }
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was hoping for. Thanks a lot fortegente.

Comment: It's throwing out an error. The browser doesn't seem to like the 9 in if(val<9)

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to fadeToggle with jQuery. See details here:

http://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/

```
<script>
    function flash(id) {
        $('#'+id).fadeToggle();
    }

    var blinker = 2000;
    var timeIn = setInterval(function() {
        flash('sign');
    }, blinker);
</script>
```

Comment: When you provide an answer avoid to paste only a link to the answer this could be a comment ... try to improve your answer with an example or explanation about the code

Answer (score 0):

Here's a <kbd>**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/gSpat/)**</kbd>

```
setInterval(function() {
  $('.sign').animate({ opacity: '0' }, 800).animate({ opacity: '1' }, 800);
}, 2000);
```